# I wanna attach a tooltip to ngx-newsticker events array "for each item"

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have a news bar and I used ngx-newsticker, I need to attach a tooltip for each item in the news bar.  However, the plugin takes an array of string as shown below.

I tried to loop throw the array but it doesn't work:

```
    <div class="M_announcementDiv" *ngIf="announcementsArrInTicker && announcementsArrInTicker.length>0">
  <div class="container">
    <div placement="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="announcementsArrInTicker">
      <ngx-newsticker title="{{'ANNOUNCEMENTS'|translate}}" [events]="announcementsArrInTicker"  [interval]="interval"></ngx-newsticker>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to push the current item to the tooltip in this line instead of pushing
the whole array.

```
<div placement="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="announcementsArrInTicker">
```

and this is the ts function that retrieves the data:

```
getGeneralAnnouncements() {
// this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
this.isAuthenticated =false;

this.newsService.searchGeneralAnnouncements(this.searchModel, this.isAuthenticated).subscribe(res => {
this.announcementArr = res;
  res.announcements.map((announcement) => {
    if(this.translate.currentLang=="ar"){
      this.announcementsArrInTicker.push(announcement.bodyAr);

    }else{
      this.announcementsArrInTicker.push(announcement.bodyEn);

    }
  });
}, error => {
  // this.businessException = errorsUtility.getBusinessException(error);   //this.notificationService.showNotification(this.businessException.message, 
 NotificationType.Error);
})
}
```